# Finding position of the first TRUE of a series of `n` TRUEs

Tags: r, performance, count, boolean

From a vector of TRUE/FALSE

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(1503501) > 0
```

**I am seeking for a performant (fast) method for getting the position of the first TRUE of the first series of `n` TRUEs.**

The vectors (`x`) I am dealing with contain exactly `1503501` elements (with the exception of some of them that are much shorter). Below is my current solution. It uses for loop but for loops are extremely slow in R. Are there nicer and especially faster solutions?

```
n = 20

count = 0
solution = -1
for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i]){
        count = count + 1
        if (count == n){solution = i+1-n; break}
    } else {count = 0}
}
print(solution)
1182796
```

I was thinking about using vectorized functions and doing something like `y = which(x)` or eventually `y = paste(which(x))` and seek for particular pattern but I am not sure how to do that.

Comment: Fair enough question (+1), but have you just invented 'performant'?

Comment: Ha ha. Well I'm ESL. But I'm not totally wrong in using the word `performant` (see [this post](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/38945/what-is-wrong-with-the-word-performant))

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `Rcpp`:

```
library(Rcpp)
cppFunction('int fC(LogicalVector x, int n) {
  int xs = x.size();
  int count = 0;
  int solution = -1;
  for (int i = 0; i < xs; ++i) {
    if (x[i]){
      if (++count == n){solution = i+2-n; break;}
    } else {
      count = 0;
    }
  }
  return solution;
}')
```

Here is a small benchmarking study:

```
f1 <- function(x,n) {
  count = 0
  solution = -1
  for (i in 1:length(x)){
    if (x[i]){
      count = count + 1
      if (count == n){solution = i+1-n; break}
    } else {count = 0}
  }
  solution
}


set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(150350100) > 0
n = 20

print(f1(x,n)==fC(x,n))
# [1] TRUE


library(rbenchmark)
benchmark(f1(x,n),fC(x,n))
#       test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1 f1(x, n)          100  80.038  180.673    63.300   16.686          0         0
# 2 fC(x, n)          100   0.443    1.000     0.442    0.000          0         0
```

[**Updated benchmark**]

```
# Suggested by BondedDust
tpos <- function(x,pos) { rl <- rle(x); len <- rl$lengths; 
                          sum(len[ 1:(which( len == pos & rl$values==TRUE)[1]-1)],1)}

set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(1503501) > 0
n = 20

print(f1(x,n)==fC(x,n))
# [1] TRUE
print(f1(x,n)==tpos(x,n))
# [1] TRUE


benchmark(f1(x,n),fC(x,n),tpos(x,n),replications = 10)
#         test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
# 1   f1(x, n)           10   4.756  110.605     4.735    0.020          0         0
# 2   fC(x, n)           10   0.043    1.000     0.043    0.000          0         0
# 3 tpos(x, n)           10   2.591   60.256     2.376    0.205          0         0
```

Comment: Being able to break out will certainly improve performance. (Our values do agree.)

Comment: I'm a bit surprised tpos was better than f1, but rle is probably optimized for what it does.

Comment: Oh! I had no idea that something like Rcpp existed! This is so powerful to be able to quickly define our function in C within the R environment. +1 Thanks a lot! This answer will have a much broader application to me than only the question asked in the present post.

Comment: @BondedDust, I was surprised too. Also, I'm surprised that `rle` is not an internal function, and it's quite simple.

Comment: Worth noting, also, is `compiler::cmpfun`: `cmpf1 = compiler::cmpfun(f1)`; `rbenchmark::benchmark(f1(x, n), fC(x, n), tpos(x, n), cmpf1(x, n), replications = 10)`

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at this transcript (using only a much smaller random sample). I think it fairly clear that it will be easy to write a function that picks out the first position that satisfies the joint condition and use cumsum on the lengths up to that point:

```
> x = rnorm(1500) > 0

> rle(x)
Run Length Encoding
  lengths: int [1:751] 1 1 1 2 1 3 1 2 2 1 ...
  values : logi [1:751] FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE FALSE TRUE ...
> table( rle(x)$lengths )

  1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9 
368 193  94  46  33  10   2   4   1 
> table( rle(x)$lengths , rle(x)$values)

    FALSE TRUE
  1   175  193
  2   100   93
  3    47   47
  4    23   23
  5    21   12
  6     5    5
  7     2    0
  8     3    1
  9     0    1
> which( rle(x)$lengths==8 & rle(x)$values==TRUE)
[1] 542
> which( rle(x)$lengths==7 & rle(x)$values==TRUE)
integer(0)
> which( rle(x)$lengths==6 & rle(x)$values==TRUE)
[1]  12 484 510 720 744
```

This is my candidate function:

```
 tpos <- function(x,pos) { rl <- rle(x); len <- rl$lengths; 
            sum(len[ 1:(which( len == pos & rl$values==TRUE)[1]-1)],1)}
 tpos(x,6)
#[1] 18
```

Note that I subtracted one from the first index so the length of the first qualifying run of TRUE's would not be added in, and then added one to that sum so that the position of the first such TRUE would be calculated. I'm guessing the positon of the first run of n-TRUEs will be distributed as one of the extreme value distributions (although it's not always monotonic increase)

```
>  tpos(x,8)
[1] 1045
> tpos(x,8)
[1] 1045
> tpos(x,9)
[1] 1417
> tpos(x,10)
[1] 4806
> tpos(x,11)
[1] 2845
> tpos(x,12)
Error in 1:(which(len == pos & rl$values == TRUE)[1] - 1) : 
  NA/NaN argument
> set.seed(1)
> x = rnorm(30000) > 0
> tpos(x,12)
[1] 23509
```

Answer (score 0):

You can take your vector and add a FALSE (zero) to the beginning and remove the end and then add this augmented vector to your original vector (as 0/1 vectors of integers), and then do the same thing again by adding one more FALSE (zero) to the beginning from the previously augmented vector and removing the end and then adding this to your currently rolling sum vector (again, adding as vectors of integers) and do this until you have added up n total shifted copies of your vector. Then you can do which(sum_x == n) where sum_x is the sum vector and take the minimum returned by which(), and subtract n-1 and this will get you the start of the first occurrence of n TRUE's in a row. This will work much faster if n is somewhat small compared to the length of your vector.